# how to select a button and style by using emotion styles in MUI

Tags: html, css, material-ui, emotion

i want to give a `margin-right` to my button. am using mui 5 `Button variant='contained'`.
wrote a custom css style using `styled` component in mui and targeted the `Box`.

```
const Wrapper = styled(Box)({
    display: 'flex',
    margin: '0, 3%, 0, auto',
    '& .button':{
        marginRight: '40px',
    }
})
```

here i need to target my button element and to give a marginRight property to it.the above code doesn't works

```
<Wrapper>
      <Button variant='contained'>Login</Button>

      <Typography>Become a Seller</Typography>
      <Typography>More</Typography>

    </Wrapper>
```

i want to target the button element above. but i don't know how to select the button and to give styles by using `Styled` imported from `import styled from '@emotion/styled';`

Comment: Is [that](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#emotion) what you need ?

Comment: i didn't find anything usefull over there. here i need to select my button  inside my wrapper function and using `emotion styled` and targeting `Box`

Comment: found solution to target the button we need to select with `>` instead of `.`

Answer (score 0):

To select a element inside the styled component. we need to select with `>` instead of `.` along with `&` operator

here i changed my code to this

```
const Wrapper = styled(Box)({
    display: 'flex',
    margin: '0, 3%, 0, auto',
    '& > button':{
        marginRight: '40px',
    }
})
```